# ¿Cómo hacer que un formulario acepte exclusivamente un tipo de dato?

Tags: html, formularios, imagen

Dado un formulario cuya finalidad es aceptar exclusivamente imagenes, **¿cómo puedo lograr que en el explorador de archivos no se pueda cambiar a *Todos los archivos*?**

## Formulario:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Formulario</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Bienvenido</h1>

 <form action="imageServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
   <input type="file" name="imagen" accept="image/*"/>
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="submit" />
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

A pesar de tener el campo `accept="image/*"` permite cambiar.

---

Comment: no se puede hacer eso. Porque el explorador no forma parte del navegador.

Comment: @hawks vale, pues una pregunta a parte si no te importa. ¿Como puedo comprobar que el archivo enviado es una imagen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El input de tipo [file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) tiene una propiedad que es `files` que contiene un conjunto de objetos con informacion sobre los archivos seleccionados. Y hay una propiedad que es `type` que indica el tipo del fichero/s seleccionado/s.

En el ejemplo valido que el tipo contenga `image` pero puedes mirar todos los [mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) que hay y hacer la validación acorde tu caso.

```js
const file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload')

file.addEventListener('change', e => {
  console.log(file.files);
  if (!file.files[0].type.includes('image')){
    alert('no es imagen')
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```